# How to reset all uiviews to original frame values of nib file in ios?

Tags: ios, uiview, cgrect

I made some changes to a subviews programmatically . Now on a button click i want to revert back all the displacements i did for uiview to the values of nib .Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible unless you stored the original frames of the `UIView` objectes.